# SAS - creating counter variable for dataset sampling

Tags: sas, counter, sampling

I'm new to SAS and wondering how to randomly sample a dataset.

I create a dataset `work.seg`, then sample from that table. I want to continue sampling until the sum of the prem column in the resampled table is greater than some amount.

In my current version of the code, I think it resets `sumprem` to 0 each time, so it never exceeds the threshold, and the code just keeps running.

```
data work.seg;
    input segment $3. prem loss;
    datalines;
AAA 5000 0
AAA 3000 12584
AAA 250 245
AAA 500 678
;

data work.test;
    sumprem = 0;
    row_i=int(ranuni(777)*n)+1;
    set work.seg point=row_i nobs=n;
    sumprem=sumprem+prem_i;
    if sumprem>15000 then stop;
run;
```

Comment: Since you are new, `Proc SURVEYSELECT` is an enormously capable procedure for sampling.  Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49604667/sas-random-sampling/49608938#49608938 for select n sampling in a DATA step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using POINT= option there is no need to let the normal iteration of the data step happen.  Just add a loop and an output statement.  You might want to also put an upper bound on maximum number of samples.

```
data work.test;
  do _n_=1 to 100000 until (sumprem>15000) ;
    row_i=int(ranuni(777)*n)+1;
    set work.seg point=row_i nobs=n;
    sumprem + prem_i;
    output;
  end;
  stop;
run;
```

Comment: In case you didn't notice, @Tom changed the arithmetic assignment to a SUM statement. The syntax is `<variable> + <expression>` and causes a tacit (or implicit) retain of the variable and 0 initialization.

Comment: Also not that the implicit RETAIN is not needed since the data step iterates only once.  It is just easier than having to type the target variable name twice.

Comment: Note use of sum statement (or sum() function) will allow for sampled records with missing values of PREM.

Answer (score 2):

you just need to replace the sumprem=0 to retain statement and also prem_i is unidentified, use prem variable instead

```
 sumprem=0; /* Change this to next statement*/
 retain sumprem 0;
```